# Getting rid of "buffer has running process" confirmation when the process is a flymake process

Tags: emacs, flymake

Is there a way to tell emacs to always kill flymake processes when I'm closing the associated buffer? I don't want to get the confirmation when the only process associated with the buffer is a flymake process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a [patch](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2010-03/msg01217.html).  The gist is to modify the function that invokes flymake to use `set-process-query-on-exit-flag` to set the `process-query-on-exit-flag` variable to `nil` for the flymake process.  See also `C-h f set-process-query-on-exit-flag`.

Comment: Does this properly delete the flymake files that flymake generates?

Comment: Then this isn't very helpful. Way is really needed is an exit hook that does whatever normally happens when the fly make process exits without asking. Or at the very least, explicitly delete this file.

Comment: Did you read the question?  It's helpful for what the person actually *asked*.  If you have a different question, ask it in a different question.

Answer (score 12):

You can also turn the `process-query-on-exit-flag` off with advice:

```
(defadvice flymake-start-syntax-check-process (after
                                               cheeso-advice-flymake-start-syntax-check-1
                                               (cmd args dir)
                                               activate compile)
  ;; set flag to allow exit without query on any
  ;;active flymake processes
  (set-process-query-on-exit-flag ad-return-value nil))
```

This has the same effect as the patch above, but it does not require modifying flymake.el  .

Comment: BTW, I don't use flymake any longer. Flymake was a cool idea, but the execution was wanting.  There are problems with running flymake when you have lots of buffers open (http://www.flycheck.org/en/latest/user/flycheck-versus-flymake.html#flycheck-versus-flymake), which for me is "all the time."  Flycheck, on the other hand, seems better executed. I've switched over to flycheck and am quite happy.